# How do I create a set of characters in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'd like to create a Set of character ranges in Scala, something like A..Za..z0..9. Here's my take:

```
scala> ('A' to 'Z').toSet.union(('a' to 'z').toSet).union(('0' to '9').toSet)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(E, e, X, s, x, 8, 4, n, 9, N, j, y, T, Y, t, J, u, U, f, F, A, a, 5, m, M, I, i, v, G, 6, 1, V, q, Q, L, b, g, B, l, P, p, 0, 2, C, H, c, W, h, 7, r, K, w, R, 3, k, O, D, Z, o, z, S, d)
```

This can't be the idiomatic way to do this. What's a better way?

Comment: Pablo and Paul- I appreciate your responses. You both added to this discussion. From Pablo's answer, I found my way to the (...).toSet implementation later suggested by Paul.  However, because Paul's answer is technically more correct, I switched my accepted answer.  I learned from both of you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about this:

```
scala> ('a' to 'z').toSet ++ ('A' to 'Z') ++ ('0' to '9')
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(E, e, X, s, x, 8, 4, n, 9, N, j, y, T, Y, t, J, u, U, f, F, A, a, 5, m, M, I, i, v, G, 6, 1, V, q, Q, L, b, g, B, l, P, p, 0, 2, C, H, c, W, h, 7, r, K, w, R, 3, k, O, D, Z, o, z, S, d)
```

Or, alternatively:

```
scala> (('a' to 'z') ++ ('A' to 'Z') ++ ('0' to '9')).toSet
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(E, e, X, s, x, 8, 4, n, 9, N, j, y, T, Y, t, J, u, U, f, F, A, a, 5, m, M, I, i, v, G, 6, 1, V, q, Q, L, b, g, B, l, P, p, 0, 2, C, H, c, W, h, 7, r, K, w, R, 3, k, O, D, Z, o, z, S, d)
```

Comment: the first `toSet` is not necessary

Comment: Yes it is - otherwise you get an IndexedSeq, not a Set

Comment: he probably doesn't care about the implementation

Comment: @Pablo: You should read the title again. Also, "toSet" does not just change the implementation.

Comment: I wasn't taking him literally when he said set, and I guess I was right since the answer was picked as the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

```
('0' to 'z').filter(_.isLetterOrDigit).toSet
```

Comment: IMHO this is not very readable code. You have to know ASCII code to guess what ends up in the set.

Comment: Why not `'0' to 'z' filter(_.isLetterOrDigit) toSet`

Comment: @ziggistar: Of course this is just an optimization, you could run the range e.g. from 0 to 127. And for the other solutions you have to know ASCII as well, e.g. the assumption that the range a..z contains only letters is not true for other encodings (say EBCDIC).

Answer (score 3):

A more functional version of your code is this:

```
scala> Traversable(('A' to 'Z'), ('a' to 'z'), ('0' to '9')) map (_ toSet) reduce (_ ++ _)
```

Combining it with the above solutions, one gets:

```
scala> Seq[Seq[Char]](('A' to 'Z'), ('a' to 'z'), ('0' to '9')) reduce (_ ++ _) toSet
```

If you have just three sets, the other solutions are simpler, but this structure also works nicely if you have more ranges or they are given at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it can't be simpler than this:

```
('a' to 'z') ++ ('A' to 'Z') ++ ('0' to '9')
```

You might guess that `('A' to 'z')` will include both, but it also adds some extra undesirable characters, namely:

```
([, \, ], ^, _, `)
```

**Note:**

This will not return a `Set` but an `IndexedSeq`. I assumed you don't mind the implementation, but if you do, and do want a `Set`, just call `toSet` to the result.

Comment: That's not a set.  It actually ends up as a `Vector` (typed as `IndexedSeq`).  Also, it contains the integer values `0` through `9` not the characters.

Comment: Isn't it funny that you're downvoting the question as "not useful" when the OP has marked it as accepted?

Comment: The answer is wrong, whether or not the OP recognizes it.  Since StackOverflow is designed to be a reference for other people with the same question, it makes sense to vote based on _whether the question is answered_ not _whether the original asker is happy_.

Comment: The answer is not wrong, it's just incomplete. I've added a note now, please reconsider the downvote

Comment: Now that you have fixed `0 to 9`, it is not actually wrong, just incomplete, which does change my mind (to neutral).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate all the possible characters, doing this should generate all the values a char can take:

```
(' ' to '~').toSet
```